# WebSphere message engine start error

Tags: jms, websphere-8

I am facing a problem while starting the Websphere message engine. When I try to start the message engine it shows me this error:

```
The messaging engine Node01.MXServerINT-mifjmsbus cannot be started as there is no runtime initialized for it yet, retry the operation once it has initialized. For the runtime to successfully initialize the hosting server must be started, have its 'SIB service' already enabled, and dynamic configuration reload enabled. If this is a newly configured messaging engine and it is the first messaging engine to be hosted on this server, then it is most likely the 'SIB service' was not previously enabled and thus the server will need to be restarted. The messaging engine runtime might not be initializing because of an error while trying to start, examine the SystemOut.log of the hosting server to check for error messages indicating the problem.
```

System log:

```
BMXAA1580E - A Java Message System (JMS) error occurred. Check the JMS setup in the administrator console for the server.
psdi.util.MXApplicationException: BMXAA1580E - A Java Message System (JMS) error occurred. Check the JMS setup in the administrator console for the server.
 at psdi.iface.jms.JMSClient.<init>(JMSClient.java:194)
 at psdi.iface.jms.JMSConsumer.<init>(JMSConsumer.java:149)
 at psdi.iface.jms.JMSConsumer.<init>(JMSConsumer.java:129)
 at psdi.iface.jms.JMSConsumer.<init>(JMSConsumer.java:92)
 at psdi.iface.jms.JMSQueueConsumer.<init>(JMSQueueConsumer.java:46)
 at psdi.iface.jms.JMSQueueCronTask.createConsumer(JMSQueueCronTask.java:232)
```

Currently the message engine is in unavailable state.
I already tried to delete the WebSphere cache, restart webserver, enable the SIB Services.

[image: WebSphere Admin Console]

Any help would be appreciated.
Many thanks,

Comment: Messaging engine should start when the server starts. did you restarted the server after creating the bus and adding server to the bus? Check the SystemOut.log during server startup for any errors related to the messaging engine.

Comment: I also restart web server. SystemOut.log shows me: http://pastebin.com/VF3Xx2ih

Comment: These are messages related to your application, you have to look earlier in the log when the server starts, not the application. And look for any exceptions/errors related to the messaging engine start - `CWSIT0088E: There are currently no messaging engines in bus uijmsbus running.`. In addition - messaging engine should start by itself, you never should need to start it manually.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like due to Data source connection is not connecting to database. This can be tested using Data Source (Test Connection).